# What is the variance for $t \rightarrow 0^+$ of a Cox-Ingersoll-Ross process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-statistics

Let us define a Cox-Ingersoll-Ross process as:
$$ d X(t) = \alpha (\mu - X(t))dt + \sigma \sqrt{X(t)} dW(t)$$

with $X(t)$ distributed as a non-central Chi-square and $W(t)$ as a Wiener process.

The analytical variance of the CIR process is:

$$Var(X(t))= X(0)\bigg(\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha}\bigg)(e^{-\alpha t}-e^{-2\alpha t}) + \mu\bigg(\frac{\sigma^2}{2 \alpha}\bigg)(1-e^{-\alpha t})^2 $$

where
$\alpha \geq 0, t \geq 0, X_0 \geq 0$

What is the variance of the process for $t \rightarrow 0$? I know it is the limit $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} Var(X(t))$ and the answer should be  $$Var(X(t)) = X(0)\sigma^2$$, but it is not clear to me how to calculate it step by step.

Comment: For this to have a definite answer, I think you had better make some assumptions about $\alpha$: what happens to $\exp(-\alpha t)$ for large $t$ when $\alpha$ is negative?

Comment: @whuber I actually found out that $\alpha \geq 0$, see edit

Comment: Now that you know that $\alpha$ is nonnegative, what happens to $\exp(-\alpha t)$ for large $t$?

Comment: I have noticed, for the first time, that you specified $t\to 0$ instead of large $t$.  (Most people would not call that "asymptotic"; there are no asymptotes involved.)  What happens to $\exp(-\alpha t)$ as $t$ approaches zero?

Comment: @whuber $exp(-\alpha t) = 1$

Comment: ... and that answers your question.

Comment: @whuber But it that case the answer would be $var(X(t))=0$. The rationale behind my question was that I can't figure out why instead the answer is $Var(X(t)) = X(0)\sigma^2$.

Comment: You have just discovered that the answer you were given and the formula for the variance are inconsistent with one another.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, but this is why I contextualized the problem: I'm trying to find the variance of the CIR model for $t \rightarrow 0$. I appreciate your help, but I can do a limit myself.

Comment: There is no need to do a limit: just set $t=0$.  This function for the variance is continuous.  As I mentioned, there are no asymptotics here: it's merely a simple plug-in calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variance of the process is $Var(X(t))=0$ for $t \rightarrow 0$.

$X(0)\sigma^2t$ is instead the tangent of the variance function in $t=0$.
In fact, we can approximate with Taylor:
$$ e^{-2 \alpha t} \simeq 1 - 2 \alpha t $$
$$ e^{- \alpha t} \simeq 1-\alpha t$$

Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
Var(t) &\simeq X(0)(\frac{\sigma^2}{\alpha})[(1-\alpha t)-(1-2 \alpha t)] + \mu (\frac{\sigma^2}{2 \alpha})[1-(1-\alpha t)]^2\\
&= X(0)\sigma t + \mu \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \alpha t^2\\
&= X(0)\sigma t
\end{align}
$$
In fact we can set $\mu \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\alpha t = 0$ since we are taking the tangent, which is a linear function of $t$.

Here is the graphical representation

[image: Matlab plot of the functions]